# Android SQlite error *No such table: Account*

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have created a database table by *database browser for sqlite* and added the file in Assets folder.
i want to get the data from table and show them in TextView when i click the Button but every time i run nothing appear and the compiler say that their is no table called Account. i had watched many tutorials and every time the same error appear 
this is the code.

> Account

```
public class Account {

private String UserName;
private String Email;

public Account() {
}

public Account(String userName, String email) {
    UserName = userName;
    Email = email;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return UserName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    UserName = userName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return Email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    Email = email;
}
```

}

> DataBaseHelper

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static String DB_PATH="";
private static String DB_NAME="MyDB.db";
private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
private Context mContext;

public DbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17){
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    } else {
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {
    if (mDataBase != null){
        mDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

private boolean checkDataBase(){
    SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
    try {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path,null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        if (tempDB != null)
            tempDB.close();
        }
    return tempDB != null ? true:false;
}

public void copyDataBase(){
    try {
        InputStream myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outputFileNme = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileNme);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void openDataBase(){
    String path =  DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public void createDataBase(){
    boolean isDBExist = checkDataBase();
    if (isDBExist){

    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try  {
            copyDataBase();
        }catch (Exception ex){

        }
    }
}

public List<Account> getAllUsers(){
    List<Account> temp = new ArrayList<Account>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c;
    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Account",null);
        if (c == null) return null;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {
            Account account =  new Account(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("UserName")),c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Email")));
            temp.add(account);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e){

    }
    db.close();
    return temp;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

List<Account> lstUser = new ArrayList<Account>();
DbHelper dbHelper;
Button btnGetData;
LinearLayout container;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnGetData = findViewById(R.id.btnGetData);
    container = findViewById(R.id.container);

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    dbHelper.createDataBase();

    btnGetData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            lstUser = dbHelper.getAllUsers();
            for (Account account:lstUser){
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,null);
                TextView txtUser = addView.findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
                TextView txtEmail = addView.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

                txtUser.setText(account.getUserName());
                txtEmail.setText(account.getEmail());
                container.addView(addView);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: I'd suggest going back into DB Browser for SQLite and then check that the Account table has been defined and then that you click on File/Write Changes and then recopy the file (must be **MyDB.db**) into the assets folder (not if any subdirectory) then Delete the App's data and rerun.

Comment: @MikeT i have unistalled the application and checked the table many times and the same error occur

Comment: IF you have done all the above (works if you do), then what version is the device? Perhaps try on earlier version if it's P (I've run the code OK on API 16 and API 26, don't have a 27 device (there have been a few having difficulties with 27)).

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks after testing the code. So it would appear that the issue is that the Database is empty (perhaps not saved properly with DBBrowser for SQlite, which does appear to be quirky).

I'd advise, if using DB Browser for SQlite, to always save the database (Write Changes), Close the Database and then open the Database and check that it is as expected. Repeat until it is and then copy the file to the assets folder.

However, here's a modified version of the CopyDatabase method that may assist in detecting any issues copying the database :-

```
public boolean copyDataBase() {
    InputStream myInput;
    OutputStream myOutput;
    try {
        myInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d("COPYDB-OPN ASSET","IoException opening Asset file " + DB_NAME);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    String outputFileNme = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    try {
        myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileNme);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d("COPYDB-OPN OUT","IOException opening Output file " + outputFileNme);
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    long bytes_read = 0;
    long bytes_written = 0;
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            bytes_read = bytes_read + length;
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            bytes_written = bytes_written + length;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d("COPYDB-CPY DATA",
                "IOException Copying Data. " +
                        " Bytes Read=" + String.valueOf(bytes_read) +
                        " Bytes Written=" + String.valueOf(bytes_written));
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    try {
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("COPYDB-FINALISE","IOException Flushing/Closing Files");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    Log.d("COPYDB-COMPLETED",
            "The copy of " + DB_NAME + " has completed. " +
                    String.valueOf(bytes_written) + " bytes were copied to " + outputFileNme);
    return true;
}
```

- Basically instead of a single try/catch clause, multiple try/catch clauses have been introduced allowing any issue to be trapped and reported upon.
- The method also returns a boolean indicating whether or not it has completed successfully.
- If it does complete successfully a message is output to the log accordingly.

A slightly different CreateDatabase method could also be used :-

```
public void createDataBase() {
    boolean isDBExist = checkDataBase();
    if (isDBExist) {
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (!copyDataBase()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to Copy Database " + DB_NAME + " from the Asset file");
        }
    }
}
```

- This will throw an exception of the copy failed.

For example if the asset file is missing then something along the lines of the following would appear in the log :-

```
6-15 04:42:49.633 2252-2252/? E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 35652 of [8201f4e1c5]
    (14) os_unix.c:35652: (2) open(/data/user/0/soanswers.soanswers/databases/MyDB.db) - 
06-15 04:42:49.641 2252-2252/? E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database '/data/user/0/soanswers.soanswers/databases/MyDB.db'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:808)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:793)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:696)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:671)
        at soanswers.soanswers.DbHelperSO50867547.checkDataBase(DbHelperSO50867547.java:49)
        at soanswers.soanswers.DbHelperSO50867547.createDataBase(DbHelperSO50867547.java:115)
        at soanswers.soanswers.MainActivity.SO50867547(MainActivity.java:635)
        at soanswers.soanswers.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:140)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
06-15 04:42:49.645 2252-2252/? I/swers.soanswers: type=1400 audit(0.0:2324): avc: denied { read } for name="databases" dev="sdb3" ino=81932 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=1
06-15 04:42:49.657 2252-2252/? I/swers.soanswers: type=1400 audit(0.0:2326): avc: denied { setattr } for name="MyDB.db" dev="sdb3" ino=81933 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:system_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=file permissive=1
06-15 04:42:49.666 2252-2252/? D/COPYDB-OPN ASSET: IoException opening Asset file MyDB.db
06-15 04:42:49.666 2252-2252/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: MyDB.db
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:374)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:348)
        at soanswers.soanswers.DbHelperSO50867547.copyDataBase(DbHelperSO50867547.java:61)
        at soanswers.soanswers.DbHelperSO50867547.createDataBase(DbHelperSO50867547.java:119)
        at soanswers.soanswers.MainActivity.SO50867547(MainActivity.java:635)
06-15 04:42:49.667 2252-2252/? W/System.err:     at soanswers.soanswers.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:140)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
06-15 04:42:49.668 2252-2252/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

- Note The failed to open the database is due to the checkDatabase method checking to see if the Database exists.
- The real error, due to being unable to open the Asset file is :-

  `06-15 04:42:49.666 2252-2252/? D/COPYDB-OPN ASSET: IoException opening Asset file MyDB.db
  06-15 04:42:49.666 2252-2252/? W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: MyDB.db
          at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
          at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:374)
          at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:348)
          at soanswers.soanswers.DbHelperSO50867547.copyDataBase(DbHelperSO50867547.java:61)`

Should there not be an error, then the log would containing something similar to :-

```
06-15 04:57:57.337 2384-2384/soanswers.soanswers D/COPYDB-COMPLETED: The copy of MyDB.db has completed. 8192 bytes were copied to /data/user/0/soanswers.soanswers/databases/MyDB.db
```

- Note, that as the database didn't at this stage exist the log would also contain the stack-trace with `E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line ....` as the database didn't exist.